# PowerShell to set Check-in Policy

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm looking for a way to set the check-in policy in TFS via PowerShell. Ideally, I'd traverse the entire TFS project collection/project hierarchy, and turn on the Work Item required for check-in policy. I've seen and tried this guy's solution: http://www.manasbhardwaj.net/set-checkin-policies-projects-team-foundation-server-using-powershell/, but it's not working. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.WorkItemPolicy can't be found, so this approach is for naught. I've already figured out how to traverse the hierarchy, but I can't find the magic to set the policy. Anyone?

TFS 2013, on-premise. Visual Studio 2015/2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll` still ships with VS 2015/VS 2017, but it has been removed the client OM DLLs from the GAC.

In VS 2015, you can find the DLL in `C:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

In VS 2017, you can find the DLL in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

Comment: Yeah, I found that in other places, but I guess I'm not clear on how to reference it in the PowerShell script. I'm using [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("xxxx") to reference, but I guess it's not available for the script to load. I've tried using Add-Type -AssemblyName "xxx", too, but no love.

Comment: @JimRoth Using Add-Type -Path "[assembly path]"

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName "C:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll"
doesn't work. "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid."

Comment: I'm a dope. I was using -AssemblyName, not -Path, as you recommended. Thank you, Cece!!!